# JQuery passing parameter to .each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

I don't understand how jquery knows that by passing an argument (`index` in this case) to the anonymous function the index of the `<li>` element should be displayed to the console.Can somebody explain this to me?Thanks.

Comment: jQuery doesn't know. They just invoke the function you give, and pass the values to it, and you do whatever you want with them inside the function.

Comment: Whatever callback function you specify as argument for `.each`, will automatically _called_ by jQuery with two parameters, the index and the current element – how you _call_ those parameters is entirely up to you, you can call them `foo` and `bar` if you like.

Comment: `.each()` takes two parameters `Integer index, Element element`